Finding outliers in a small sized vector
Let us say I have an n element vector consisting of certain measurements with spikes that need to be located (n is small, say 5-7). My task is to locate all elements in the vector that are "much greater than the rest". A method based on calculating standard deviations (or z scores) would work well if n were large, and the number of "large" elements were small. However, n is small, and the number of "large" elements can even equal n. So, a statistical method is not going to work.
This is akin to finding the bright spots in an image, where the entire image can be bright. One could threshold the vector, for instance, but that is risky since the actual content of the vector could change. For now, I am going with the following code:
pnormalize=p/np.max(p)
pthreshold=np.where(pnormalize>0.6,1,0)

The unease I have with this is that the choice of 0.6 is arbitrary. In practice, with vectors like [13.45 0.3 1.4 0.8 11.1], which result in [1 0 0 0 1], this works, this could have easily failed for [13.45 0.3 1.4 0.8 7.1], where it is "obvious" I have two elements that are much larger than the rest, but the code provides a false negative. I cannot lower the threshold arbitrarily, as noise does exist, and don't want any false positives either.
An even bigger problem is that if there are no spikes, this would give me several "spikes", depending on what the noise is.
Any suggestions?

The suggested link does not work since the number of outliers (spikes) is not small compared to the size of the dataset.

Does this answer your question? Is there a numpy builtin to reject outliers from a list

@ti7, no. As explained, no statistical method will work. The link you have provided implicitly assumes that the number of outliers is small compared to the size of the dataset.

hmm.. I doubt that's truly the case ("no statistical method") and IQR specfically may help here .. though you may find you do still need a bespoke wrapper which does an initial selection round of a statistical filter or its arguments based upon some heuristics! really though, you may have identified an ideal case for a neural network

I made it "work" by combining the threshold with a second threshold on the absolute value (making some assumptions about the noise background). It will break once I get an abnormally high value of noise. Hate having to use absolute values as thresholds, but that is what it needed. I will look into neural networks someday when I have time.

excellentish - please do make an Answer with your solution! casually, it might be a good idea to try to flag and collect anomalous collections for analysis, perhaps by absolute range..

@ti7 Thanks. Done as suggested.

As suggested by @ti7, I am posting what I did. This is not an ideal solution as it is not robust, but at least it avoids the false positive / false negative problem, for now.
   q1=np.where(((p1/p1.max(axis=1,keepdims=True)>0.6) & (p1>5)),1,0)

The value of 5 picked above is arbitrary and places an upper bound on the background noise. This is the thing that made this work, and also is its biggest weakness.
Just as recap: p1 is a 5 element vector, and I have thousands of p1s coming in each minute from the measurement channels. For now, I am storing all these to a file, and periodically running the script on the file as it grows to a certain size, but will work on a realtime solution once I have the python script integrated as a LabVIEW node.
